# Best practises for managing Ansible-galaxy roles and the software dependencies (update/install)

Tags: ansible

I recently find ansbile-galaxy, which will allow us to resue the ansible roles from others. But my confuse is how to manage ansible-galaxy roles and the dependencies software? For exameple : If i have the external role of "geerlingguy.mysql", then what is the best practies for merging it to my own project , and if i want to use the customzied version of mysql 5.7, then how to set ? how to set the custimized download URL ? and how to locally cached the mysql5.7 installation into my local ansible management server ?

Comment: Your question is very unspecific. Try to write a clear question on whats your problem. You also should write what you have tried to solve the problem, maybe give an example of your current code etc. 

See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the role by setting variables provided by the role. If there is no variable for your configuration, you can:

- Fork the role and make a PR to support the configuration.
- Create a own role wich is depending on the other role (See dependencies of roles) and add your custom tasks.
- Write your own role and use parts of the other role. It's open source.